# Verbose Mongoose validation errors?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I perform a `validate` on a Mongoose path but return a more verbose error message?  In the example below, there are four possible errors that I would like to return.  Although I am logging them to the console, I would rather send them back as an error, instead of simply "Invalid file size":

```
schema.path('size').validate(function (size) {

    if (typeof size == 'undefined' || size == null) { console.log('no size supplied'); return false; }
    if (typeof size != 'number') { console.log('size not a number'); return false; }
    if (size < 0) { console.log('size is negative'); return false; }
    if (Math.floor(size) != Number(size)) { console.log('size is decimal'); return false; }

    return true;

}, 'Invalid file size');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain multiple `validate` calls on the same path and give them each their own error message:

```
schema.path('size')
    .validate(function (size) {
        return !(typeof size == 'undefined' || size == null);
    }, 'no size supplied')
    .validate(function (size) {
        return (typeof size == 'number');
    }, 'size not a number')
    .validate(function (size) {
        return (size >= 0);
    }, 'size is negative')
    .validate(function (size) {
        return (Math.floor(size) == Number(size));
    }, 'size is decimal');
```

Comment: Cool!  But are the subsequent evaluations supposed to fail on `true` or `false`?  For example, you're returning the error "size not a number" when `typeof size == 'number'`.

Comment: A validation failure is indicated by the function returning `false`. I inverted each of your boolean checks to make this example.  So if `typeof size == 'number'` returns `false`, then `size` isn't a number and you get the "size not a number" validation failure.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  The double-negative for the fist item threw me for a loop.  Love the chaining.  :)